# What's the best way using vanilla js to force confirmation on publish button?

Tags: javascript, publish, buttons

I am trying to force a confirmation in certain cases in the editor screen. I'm using something like this after selecting the publishButton:

```
publishButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    confirm('You need a layout');
});
```

But if I hit "cancel" at the confirm box it still publishes. How can I block it?

Answer (score 0):

You can call [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on the event object that is passed to the handler:

```js
publishButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (!confirm('You need a layout')) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

which stops the event being passed on to the next handler.

Comment: Wait, this doesn't work, it still just updates as before.

Comment: Huh, OK. You could also try `return false`, but preventDefault ought to work. (Unless the publish action isn't actually bound to this element as a click handler, but that would be strange.)